# Set propertie to related nodes that are already created in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo, neo4j-browser

I'm using `py2neo` in Python to run my Cypher queries.
I'm trying to create Person nodes and relationships between then.
My DataFrame is like this:

```
df
>>> id_user      name                 follows.profiles
     a_123       Mc Marcão <3    [a_134, a_934, a_145, a_988]
     a_234       john                       a_111
     a_934       alice                       NaN
       :           :                          :
       :           :                          :
```

So here we can see that a Person can follows multiple persons, because `follows.profiles` is a list.

So this is what I did:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    graph.run('''
    UNWIND $label3 as follow_profile
    MERGE (p1:Profile { id_user: $label1, name: $label2 })
    MERGE (p1)-[:FOLLOWS]->(p2:Profile { id_user: follow_profile })
    ''', parameters = {'label1': row['id_user'],
                       'label2': row['name'],
                       'label3': row['follows.profiles']
                      })
```

So the nodes are created and their relationships too.
Now I want to set labels to the nodes relateds. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All the nodes you created already have a `Profile` label. But the neo4j Browser does not show the labels since normally you want identifying information to display for each node. However, the Browser does allow you to specify a different color for each label.

See [the documentation](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-browser/#browser-styling) for how to do that.